# WSO2IS logging client IP into file wso2carbon.log

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an environment where WSO2IS is behind a balancer and would like the client IP also be logged into file wso2carbon.log beyond http_access.log file.

Answer (score 0):

on application log we need to manually parse the value to log. you shall get the IP address from request. You may add this to Thread local and configure it as pattern layout[5].

```
   String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
   if (ipAddress == null) {  
       ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }
```

You may use request header "X-Forwarded-For"[1].

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
               prefix="http_access_management_console_" suffix=".log"
               pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;" />
```

[2]

[1].https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Proxies_Support
[2].https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Access+Logs

[3].http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

[4].http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html
[5].https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

Comment: @Poorman , Thank you!

But what I need is to be logged in automatically on file wso2carbon.log , I had looked this documentation but could not accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: I don't think you can do it by configuring it. You should implement one like in [5]

Answer (score 0):

If you can programmatically get the User's IP, then you can write a User Operation Event Listener [1] and print logs. A sample is in [2].

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/08/user-operation-event-listener-in-wso2.html
[2] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/08/writing-user-operation-event-listener.html